# sql get previous month

Tags: sql

I need to get the previous month and year when typed in. So if a user types 201412 then it should return 201411. If they type 201501 then it should return 201401.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Where are they typing it in?

Comment: Please read how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. We need your structure to be more specific and provide us an example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You already got an answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33826553/821786 (this time it is not `+x`, but `-1`. The solution is the same)

Comment: Dec 2014 -> Nov 2014, but Jan 2015 -> Jan 2014...?!?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this on a SQL Server database would be to create a date element out of your string, convert it to a date type, then use the function dateadd and add -1 month (subtract one month if you like)

Like this:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CAST(LEFT(201401,4)+'-'+RIGHT(201401,2)+'-01' AS DATE))
```

The steps broken down:

1. Get the year by selecting the 4 leftmost characters
2. Get the month by selecting the 2 rightmost characters
3. Add the separators '-' and 01 with the previous two elements to get a string with a valid format to be converted
4. Convert the string to a datetype to enable date operations
5. Use the dateadd function to add -1 month to the date element
6. Fingers crossed for usable input that wont break your code

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
 DECLARE @dateAsNumber VARCHAR(8);
SET @dateAsNumber = '198705';

DECLARE @DateConvertedFromNumber DATETIME; 
SELECT  @DateConvertedFromNumber = CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @dateAsNumber
        + '01'))

SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,   DATEADD(YEAR, -1,
                                              @DateConvertedFromNumber), 112),
             6) AS 'Year Before'

SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,   DATEADD(MONTH, -1,
                                              @DateConvertedFromNumber), 112),
             6) AS 'Month Before'
```

Comment: There should be a tick under the votes for the answer that you can click on. That should mark it as the answer.